# Pathfinder divide tool on object with gradient mesh

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder, gradient-mesh

I'm using Illustrator CC, and have a tear-drop shaped object which has a gradient mesh applied to it. I need to use the pathfinder divide tool in combination with another simple shape to take a chunk out of the teardrop, but the pathfinder tools don't seem to have any effect on an object with gradient mesh applied. Am I missing something obvious, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply not possible to use any Pathfinder operation if an object contains a mesh.

You may be able to use a **clipping mask** or **opacity mask** to hide a portion of your teardrop rather than trying to remove a portion.

[image: clipping mask]

Comment: Ok, so how DO we divide it, or cut it, or scissor it, snip it, or crop it? My mesh shapes throw off all my group dimensions for operation like 3D rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Late to this, but anyone else with this issue may find my results helpful:

How to clip a gradient mesh into a group of objects/paths.
What?: I want to fill my large group of objects with a colour that is a gradient mesh.

1. Make your gradient mesh separately in a shape (I chose a rectangle).
2. Make sure your artwork (mass of objects) is grouped together.
3. Make sure you've outlined your strokes.
4. **Select your grouped objects and make them into a compound stroke. (Object > Compound Path > Make)**
5. Arrange the Gradient Mesh rectangle to be behind your grouped objects.
6. Move the Gradient Mesh into place behind your artwork, as you want it fill the objects.
7. Make sure the Gradient Mesh rectangle and group of objects are both selected.
8. Right-click > Create Clipping Mask

VOILA!

[image: End Result]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can expand all the gradient and then use pathfinder divide tool to cut what you want. Beware that you won't be able to change the gradient afterwards. (It will transform all the colors in the gradient in objects).

Comment: You can't expand gradient meshes.